# Can I take advantage of Yugabytes compatability?

Tags: sql, database, cassandra, distributed-database, yugabytedb

Yugabyte seems to support Redis, Cassandra and SQL queries. Do they work with each other? For example, can I write data with Cassandra API and later perform SQL queries against them?

Answer (score 0):

These APIs do not work with each other as is, meaning you would not be able to query YCQL data from YSQL. This is because the data types are all not always present in the other APIs, and they often have different semantics.

That said, we get asked this a lot and the plan is to enable this scenario using a foreign data wrapper. So, in effect, you would be able to "import" the YCQL table into the YSQL side and use it there. Note that PostgreSQL already has a bunch of these wrappers (for example, see this generic list of [PG FDWs here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers) - it has entries for Cassandra and Redis). The idea is to re-use/enhance these and get them to work out of the box.

If you're interested, please open a GitHub issue and we can continue there. Would love to understand your use-case better to make sure we are able to address it and work with you closely on this.